# I need to run two functions one after another in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Basically I have a flutter project where I have to parse JSON data from REST API. First I had to perform Post Request in order to obtain "UUID". Then used this parameter (UUID) created GET request to use UUID and get order information using REST API again. I created two buttons, one for POST request and another for GET request. Now what I want to do is perform these two operations (1st POST, 2nd GET) by just clicking one button. I am stuck with this problem. Maybe I should use the VoidCallBack function? or another method?

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'ordertaxi_model.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}


class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
    Map uuid;
    String data;
  void orderTaxi() async {
    var data = {
      'api_key': 'this is my API key, sorry can not show',
      'phone': '1111',
      'street': 'Testttttt',
      'house': '11',
      'appartment': '11',
      'dst': 'Testtttttt',
      'moderation_required': 'yes',
    };

    var res = await http.post('rest api can not show', body: data);
    uuid = json.decode(res.body);
    if (res.statusCode != 200) throw Exception('http.post error: statusCode= ${res.statusCode}');
    print(uuid['response']['uuid']);
  }

    Future<String> orderInfo() async {
      var params = {
        'api_key': 'rest api can not show',
        'uuid': uuid['response']['uuid'],
      };
      var query = params.entries.map((p) => '${p.key}=${p.value}').join('&');

      var res = await http.get('rest api can not show?$query');
      if (res.statusCode != 200) throw Exception('http.get error: statusCode= ${res.statusCode}');
      var info = json.decode(res.body);
      setState(() {
        String data = info['response']['message'];
        print(data);
      });

    }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('X-Fit Test'),),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed:(){
          orderTaxi();
        },
      ),
      body:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by adding the second function `orderInfo()` at the end of the first one like this

```dart
void orderTaxi() async {
    var data = {
      'api_key': 'this is my API key, sorry can not show',
      'phone': '1111',
      'street': 'Testttttt',
      'house': '11',
      'appartment': '11',
      'dst': 'Testtttttt',
      'moderation_required': 'yes',
    };

    var res = await http.post('rest api can not show', body: data);
    uuid = json.decode(res.body);
    if (res.statusCode != 200) throw Exception('http.post error: statusCode= ${res.statusCode}');
    print(uuid['response']['uuid']);
    orderInfo(); // Add it here
  }

    Future<String> orderInfo() async {
      var params = {
        'api_key': 'rest api can not show',
        'uuid': uuid['response']['uuid'],
      };
      var query = params.entries.map((p) => '${p.key}=${p.value}').join('&');

      var res = await http.get('rest api can not show?$query');
      if (res.statusCode != 200) throw Exception('http.get error: statusCode= ${res.statusCode}');
      var info = json.decode(res.body);
      setState(() {
        String data = info['response']['message'];
        print(data);
      });

    }
```

**OR**

you can await the first one before calling the second one in your `onPressed` like this

```
onPressed:() async {
  await orderTaxi();
  orderInfo();
},
```

Comment: Thank you, you save me